# How to have the player camera manager's camera attach to a spring arm of a character?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a character blueprint with a spring arm. The blueprint does not have a camera. It's my understanding that the player camera manager brings its own camera and will use it, which I do see happening when I run the project. The camera is attaching at the origin, though, and not on the spring arm.

Is there a way to tell the player camera manager to attach to the spring arm, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the attachment you want, you’ll likely just want to use a UCameraComponent instead, and make sure it’s a child of the SpringArm in the attachment hierarchy.